# change the look of Edit Text box in android

Tags: android, editbox

I want to change the way the edit text view looks like... I have found a few answers but they somehow don't solve my purpose... 
Please kindly provide solutions.

Comment: Please give a better description of what you're trying to archive.

Comment: I want to change the look of the Edit box .. right now it just seems lyk a rectangle with rigid ends .. iw ant to give it a better gui effect.. how do i do dt ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try .

You can do something like this to make a rounded edit box:

Make styyles.xml in values folder.

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#E7E7E7"
    android:height="10dp"/>

<corners
    android:radius="5dp"/>
```

You can then use it in xml like :

```
<EditBox

    style="@style/Edit_box_background"
    other attributes....
    />
```

Comment: Incomplete answer. Answer by jheneghan is better.

Answer (score 54):

Just to make the comments above a bit clearer:

You should create a file in drawables. 
e.g:   textinputborder.xml..

Then add the following code for the border shape and color to that file:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#00000000" />    
<stroke android:width="2.5dp" 
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<corners
android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then use this shape for the edit text widget inside an activity xml file as required:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/searchBox"        
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="45dp"
     android:background="@drawable/textinputborder"
     android:hint="@string/Search"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" >

 </EditText>
```

Answer (score 5):

**1. Creating Background Drawable for EditText**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke
        android:width="1.5dp"                   
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />           

    <corners 
        android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

**2. Setting up EditText**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@drawable/stroke_box"           //apply background drawable
    android:padding="8dp" />                            //for better effect
```

---

[image]