# Fixed-size multi-line EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an EditText that I want to use so people can input a short bio.

So I am trying to make it so it's fixed at, for example, a box that is 4 lines high. I don't want it to "scale" or "shift" with the input -- I'm trying to make it a fixed box of a fixed number of lines with word-wrap.

I did try adding `lines="4"` and `maxLines="4"` and `inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"` but it doesn't quite seem to be right. When I set text, it appears in the middle of the EditText (and not the upper left), and it seems to let me hit enter a whole lot so I can have a word in the first row and then a character like 20 rows down.

Current XML:

```
    <EditText
        android:background="#00ff00" 
        android:id="@+id/editTextId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="4"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:gravity="left|top"/>
```

I'm using a background of green so I can more easily see it for now. Right now this lets you type as much as you want, but I want to limit it to the space as given.

Comment: Try looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778187/change-the-look-of-edit-text-box-in-android

Comment: You might want to show your entire XML layout along with a screenshot that shows what is not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Added XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in no built code to achieve what you need. But here is a workaround -

```
private String enteredText;

edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (edtText.getLineCount() > 4) {
                    edtText.setText(enteredText);
                    edtText.setSelection(edtText.getText().length()); //This statement is to move the cursor at the end of the text otherwise it'll be moved to the start of the text.
                }
                else {
                    enteredText = edtText.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Where does "enteredText" come from? Is nothing done with "s"?

Comment: That's being set in else block.

Comment: It is also used in the block before it: "edtText.setText(enteredText)"

Comment: Yes, but first else block will get executed and enteredText will get populated.

Comment: Nevermind I see now, I missed the string declaration up top so I was confused where it was coming from. I tested this out and it works as desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to fix the centered text issue add:

```
android:gravity="top|left"
```

To prevent the user from inputting more then 4 lines, you'll need to do it by code.
Add a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText`, and check the number of lines after each text-change:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
   onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      // Check number of lines here
   }
};
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: How do I check the number of lines exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this attribute to your edittext

```
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Comment: It's already part of my edittext. It doesn't actually cap the amount of input you can give it. It just caps the immediate viewing window.